# Can I use react to build out a static HTML, CSS, JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, static

I am a front end content developer working within the confines of content assets. I build my html css and js files in vscode and then upload the static files to the cms.

Not great for getting lots of framework experience.

I am hoping that I can use react, or angular, or something! To build components and pages and then use npm run build to construct the framework files into the relevant static html, css and js markup. Which I can then copy and paste into the content fields on the site.

Is something like this possible?

Ultimately I’m hoping for a block of code that looks like:

```
<style>
/* styles here */
</styles>

<div>
<!— elements here —>
</div>

<script>
// js here
</script>
```

So that I can copy paste that block into an asset container.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool named Webpack that bundles all files to one file of each type but i don't think it can bundle all files to one file!
You can read it's documents below:

https://webpack.js.org/

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/